# Discord API / Restcord : Create private channel

Tags: php, api, bots, discord

I'm trying to create private channels on Discord using Restcord, a PHP library that is very closely mapped to the Discord API.

Currently, I have managed to create voice channels, but all users on the server are able to see and join the channels. How can I make the channels so they are only available when invited ?

My current test code is :

```php
$discord = new \RestCord\DiscordClient(['token' => config('services.discord.bot_token')]);
$channel = $discord->guild->createGuildChannel([
    'guild.id'              => config('services.discord.guild_id'),
    'name'                  => 'lobby_' . uniqid(),
    'type'                  => 2, // Voice
    'permission_overwrites' => [
     ],
]);
$invitation = $discord->channel->createChannelInvite([
    'channel.id' => $channel->id,
]);

return "https://discordapp.com/invite/{$invitation->code}";
```

Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated, either with Restcord or directly using the API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `permission_overwrites` field. This fields accepts arrays of the [overwrite object](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#overwrite-object) kind.

Example:

```php
$discord = new \RestCord\DiscordClient(['token' => <token>]);
$channel = $discord->guild->createGuildChannel([
    'guild.id'              => config(<your guild ID>),
    'name'                  => '<channel name>',
    'type'                  => 2, // Voice
    'permission_overwrites' => [
        'id'                => <role OR user id>,
        'type'              => 'role' (if id is role) OR 'user' (if id is single user),
        'allow'             => <permission ID for allowed permissions>,
        'deny'              => <permissions ID for denied permissions>
     ]
]);
```

Note that if you'd leave "allow" and "deny" as 0 (default value), the role/user with id 'id' would have the same permissions as otherwise defined server-wide. To get the permissions ID for a certain set of permissions, use a Discord Permission Calculator like [this one](https://dpermcalc.neocities.org/#1049600) (here the ID is called permission number).

Hope it helps!